# Writing helper method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help to write a method to sum the total number of comments a user has from all the user posts.

#### user.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

#### Post.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

#### Comment.rb

```
beongs_to :post
```

I tied this in the user's helper

```
    def all_comments(user)
       user_posts = user.posts.all
        user_posts.each do |post|
         return post.comments.count ++
        end
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that came to my mind was as follows;

```
Comment.where(post_id: @user.posts.pluck(:id)).count
```

Comment: In the rails console, it works, how do you scope it under the user model

Comment: Which one do you need? Number of comments or comments records?

Comment: both of them. The count and the comment records

Comment: Okay, add this line to your user model;
`has_many :received_comments, through: :posts, source: :comments` I wrote it momentarily, it may be wrong  You can access with `user.received_comments` if run correctly

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right and will give you the right results but it will be slow if the User has a lot comments. `count` will perform an SQL `COUNT` query, in short it will count one by one and will perform very slow, use `size` instead to avoid excessive queries.

```
Comment.where(post_id: @user.posts.pluck(:id)).size
```

Comment: While I agree that `size` preferred over `count` I disagree with the reason you gave. There are only two ways to count the number of elements in an ActiveRecord relation – you can count the elements in the database or you can load the elements into memory and determine the length of the array in memory. Counting in the DB is actually much faster than the second option. But only if the relation was already loaded before then determine the length in memory is preferred. See: https://mensfeld.pl/2014/09/activerecord-count-vs-length-vs-size-and-what-will-happen-if-you-use-it-the-way-you-shouldnt/

Comment: You are right maybe I needed to clarify that. Size will determine which is the best option.